# Duplicate the flowers/leaves to the bottom part of the image

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How do I copy or duplicate the flowers and leaves at the top of the image to the bottom part of the image that blends seamlessly with the textured background in Photoshop?

[image]

Comment: "With difficulty". There is no standard copy method that does what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `Image > Mode > RGB` to convert the image to an RGB image (it's in Index Mode)
- Duplicate the layer
- `Edit > Transform > Rotate 180°` on the duplicate layer
- Add a **layer Mask** to the duplicate layer
- Grab a brush and paint black on the Mask to hide portions of the top layer

[image]

The masked areas in red here:

[image]

You don't even need to be *that* precise when painting. Soft edges on the mask will assist in the two layers blending together better.

[image]